# Using For loop to select data from excel_vba syntax

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use vba to do some data mining. I have excel spreadsheet and writing a code to select data from a row. Each column has separate variables but the row represents all the variables for that particular set.

I want to write a for loop for selecting a cell and assigning the value of that cell to a particular variable.

For counter = 7 To 57

Ca = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(g, counter)

What would be correct syntax to assign value of say cell g7 to variable Ca?

Thank you,
AJ

Answer (score 0):

> What would be correct syntax to assign value of say cell g7 to variable Ca?

```
Ca = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(7, 7)

Syntax : .Cells(Row,Column)
```

Similarly `G8` would be `Cells(8,7)`

or

```
Ca = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("G" & counter)

Where counter is 7
```

---

**APPLYING THIS TO YOUR CODE**

You can write your code

```
For counter = 7 To 57

Ca = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(g, counter)
```

as

```
For counter = 7 To 57
    Ca = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(counter,7)
```

OR

```
For counter = 7 To 57
    Ca = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("G" & counter)
```